# ETA for print job showing negative in Repetier host

Tags: prusa-i3, slic3r, repetier

I'm using Repetier host 1.0.6, and ever since adding default retraction settings, the "ETA" showing during a print job is negative:

[image]

It stays this way throughout the print job, which is no fun, since having a real ETA is super convenient.

Here are my retraction settings in Slic3r, for which I only changed `length` from zero to 5, and changed `lift Z` from zero to 2:

[image]

Why do I have a negative ETA value?

Comment: First thing:  revert these settings and see if the problem remains or not.   Second thing:  clearly you're printing with antimatter!  :-)